# AWS Lambda unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas Serverless

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mongodb-atlas

The error I receive :

```
  "errorMessage": "dev-pe-0.vvwclmg.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64207dd34375c6ac1adb4bf4, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('dev-pe-0.vvwclmg.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('dev-pe-0.vvwclmg.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname')>]>",
  "errorType": "ServerSelectionTimeoutError"
```

Resources I've set up :

- VPC with 2 private subnets, and security group that allows all outbound access
- Lambda function running in this VPC and the 2 private subnets and the security group
- MongoDB serverless instance, with 0.0.0.0/0 access
- Added ARN of the Lambda role to Database Access in MongoDB with permission `readWriteAnyDatabase`
- Private endpoint for MongoDB (followed https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-serverless-private-endpoint/)
- Endpoint in AWS created with `create-vpc-endpoint` call that uses the endpoint service created above

How I'm calling MongoDB (code snippet) :

```
import pymongo


client = pymongo.MongoClient(os.getenv("MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI"))


def handler(event, context):
    data = some-data-to-insert

    db = client.myDatabase
    db.myCollection.insert_many(data)
```

where `MONGODB_CONNECTION_URI` = `mongodb://dev-pe-0.vvwclmg.mongodb.net/?authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS`

This seems to be a connectivity issue - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `+srv` to my connection URI. The documentation on https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/authentication.html#aws-lambda-environment-variables is incorrect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).